# What is this character and what does it mean? (Characters identified: 仁爱)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

I've tried to find this character in dictionaries and by looking it up on Google Translate, etc., but I'm unclear- is it two characters or one? What does it mean? Thanks so much[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idQ41.jpg)

Comment: There are two characters, they are 仁爱.

A quick search explains the meaning: (page in chinese)
https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BB%81%E7%88%B1/38453

In short: Love, specifically the kind from parents to children, or from the emperor to their subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 仁爱 (ren2 ai4 in pinyin) and it can mean kind-heartness or compassion.

Answer (score 2):

仁爱（rén ài），谓宽仁慈爱；爱护、同情的感情。语出《淮南子·修务训》：“ 尧立孝慈仁爱，使民如子弟。”